# What is the difference between trend and drift?

Tags: time-series, terminology, trend

I am analyzing a time series using the unit root test. I am stuck in that I do not understand the difference between trend and drift in the time series. Is it correct to say that trend is a feature of a time series, whose average changes over time and that drift is a feature of a time series, whose variance changes over time?

Another doubt, what is the difference between the intercept in a regression model an the drift?